# Tomcat homepage (address:8080) redirects to website homepage

Tags: java, tomcat

In a server machine A a website (drupal) always run, and now I need to use tomcat (version 5.5 is installed on that machine) to use a webservice.

In another machine (B) where `tomcat7` is installed, the address `http:// localhost :8080/` shows the tomcat page, but on machine A that address redirect to the drupal website. Does this mean that port `8080` is already used by the website? The command `netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN` gives the following output:

```
...
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1719/apache2               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1719/apache2  
...
```

This means that port 8080 is open and it's already used, right?
Do I have to set tomcat on another port?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. IT seems Apache is using port 8080.

Probably the tomcat on your A machine doesn't even start - check the logs, it should report failure to bind to port.

You can go to server.xml and change the port.